# Getting element rendered by external javascript src after document ready jQuery

Tags: jquery, tripadvisor

I am trying to get some HTML elements from code that is rendered by a TripAdvisor Widget.

```
<div id="TA_selfserveprop423" class="TA_selfserveprop" style="display: none;">
    <ul id="6rK9LP" class="TA_links 6OfnXtypSP7O">
        <li id="vWwqKw7sl" class="PhWrYsr"><a href="http://www.tripadvisor.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/150_logo-11900-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&amp;uniq=423&amp;locationId=3386635&amp;lang=en_US&amp;rating=true&amp;nreviews=5&amp;writereviewlink=true&amp;popIdx=true&amp;iswide=false&amp;border=true&amp;display_version=2">
</script>
```

The code that is rendered has this element, which is the one that I want to get with jQuery:

```
<ul class="widSSPBullet">
    <li> <span class="widSSPDate">Jan 8, 2016:</span> <span class="widSSPQuote">“Great week in cabo”</span> </li>
    <li> <span class="widSSPDate">Dec 20, 2015:</span> <span class="widSSPQuote">“Plesent stay”</span> </li>
    <li> <span class="widSSPDate">Nov 1, 2015:</span> <span class="widSSPQuote">“Great stay”</span> </li>
    <li> <span class="widSSPDate">Oct 26, 2015:</span> <span class="widSSPQuote">“Marina Sol is Awesome!”</span> </li>
    <li> <span class="widSSPDate">Sep 19, 2015:</span> <span class="widSSPQuote">“Warm and welcoming and best location in...”</span> </li>
</ul>
```

However, it looks like it doesn't get rendered until after the document is ready, and maybe even after the window is loaded.  Maybe I am doing something wrong, but is there a way to wait until the element is loaded and then grab it with jQuery.  Ideally, I'd like to get the full reviews via a widget or API from Trip Advisor, but I don't think they provide that.  I looked at parsing the review page, but there is a cross origin issue with that with AJAX, and it seems so with JSONP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they really neither expose a public API nor an event system in their widget, the simplest approach would be polling:

```
var tripAdvisorCheck = setInterval(function () {
    $(".widSSPBullet").each(function () {
        clearInterval(tripAdvisorCheck);
        // do something with $(this)
    });
}, 250);
```

This runs every 250 ms, until at least one `.widSSPBullet` is found in your page, at which point it disables itself and lets you do whatever you intend to do with the element.

A more high-tech approach would be to watch for the creation of a certain element using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), downside is [non-universal browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) (at least currently) and it's more code to write as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tripAdvisorCheck = setInterval(function () {
        jQuery(".widSSPBullet").each(function () {
    reviews = jQuery(".widSSPBullet li");
    index = 0;
            showReviews(index, reviews);
            clearInterval(tripAdvisorCheck);
        });
    }, 250);

        function showReviews(index, reviews) {
                setInterval(function() {
                         jQuery("#tripAdvisorReviews").html(reviews[index]);
                         index++;
                         if (index == reviews.length) index = 0;
                     },
                  5000);
        }
</script>
<div id="tripAdvisorReviews" style="font-size:32px;color:white;">
</div>
```

There is a bit of a strange thing happening on the page though.  It seems like each time:  jQuery("#tripAdvisorReviews").html(reviews[index]); is executed the corresponding li element from ul class="widSSPBullet" is deleted ?

What I would really prefer is to be able to retrieve the full reviews from this page:  [Link To TripAdvisor Page](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g152515-d3386635-Reviews-Marina_Sol_Cabo_Leisure_Vacation_Condos-Cabo_San_Lucas_Los_Cabos_Baja_California.html) so that I could make a sort of carousel on my page.  You apparently cannot retrieve that with AJAX or JSONP ?

Answer (score 0):

There actually is an API provided:

[TripAdvisor API](http://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/)

That would probably be a better approach if the owner can get an API Key.